# java converting char to int

Tags: java, arrays

I am in the process of learning java and have become quite stuck around arrays.

What I am trying to do is assign values to characters in an array.  ie A = 0, B = 1, C = 2.  Any help would be greatly be appreciated.  Other questions similar to this haven't shown how to change A = 0 for exmaple.

```
 public class Conversion{

public static void main (String [] args)  {

String raw = "ABC";
int key = 3;

char[] list = raw.toCharArray();
int[] num = new int[raw.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++) {
num[i] = i + key;
}

System.out.print(num);




}
}
```

Thanks for the help,

Dave

Comment: What trouble do you have with the last code fragment? Have a string with all letters and return their representativ Index (charat) to get your value. Simply reassigning the values of a char doesn't work.

Comment: The system.out.print(num);  spits out a few random numbers and letters.

How do I return a representive index (charat)?

Ideally I want to use an array to store these values because the string raw "ABC" will vastly change over time.  Could contain up to 1000 characters for example.

Comment: I suggest you to go through some basic tutorials as they cover all that